# UX mode view panels like one drive but each card (block) has many fields as metadata of document. What is best pratice?

Tags: info-visualisation, best-practice, card-views

I'm trying create a mode view panels like one drive.

[image]

As you can see from image I displayed three card, each has many fields as metadata of document.

Metadata are: numerosentenza, codiceoggetto, annoruolo, parte, controparte and others 44 fields.

"Altri" show me all 44 fields.
The goal is compare this informations document each others. So when click "Altri" ALL card show me 44 fields, not only one. It is considered a good practice? before card mode view I had a table with 44 columns extended in horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't good practice to show all that info for all your cards. This is called **[Information Overload](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/information-overload)** which can lead to **[Decision Paralysis](https://www.forecast.app/blog/decision-paralysis#:%7E:text=What%20is%20decision%20paralysis%3F,salted%20caramel%20or%20white%20chocolate.)**.

Now, for your main issue: how to resolve the issues mentioned above.

**Using an accordion component** as shown in @danielillo's answer is a good idea. You could also **create a modal that shows more of this information** and maybe even add a button to compare with another item. How you do that is up to you.

Another idea is to show the information of a selected item on the right and then offer to show a comparison as well:

[image: 2 columns system for comparing]

Answer (score 0):

On desktop, you can use scrolling within a card:

[image]

<sub>*Image from [Material Design/cards behavior](https://m2.material.io/components/cards#behavior)*</sub>